# Vote for joint ownership of a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For my own questions, a few old questions, I was active on but am no no longer in a good position to administrate, could there be a way I could indicate this, so the system can perhaps roll a vote for a good person to jointy take control of and credit for the question?

Comment: Questions already (mostly) belong to the community anyway.  Is your question just about assigning future reputation points from votes to someone else?

Comment: I don't see the point in this. What questions really require long term 'administration'? Once you have the answer to your issue, you move on, no?

Comment: And to add to my above comment, if a question *does* require administration over a long period of time, it makes me believe that it's probably too vague to be an on-topic question for SO. Maybe this would be different on other sites, but honestly I don't think it makes much sense for SO.

Comment: I think you can make it community wiki to at least allow others to edit it more easily, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I've often found that I could improve my questions over time, as I gained more experience and knowledge.  (not that I support this FR).

Comment: Some questions need a bit of attention further down the line as better answers come along that you need to keep a well informed eye on, or people have questions of you that you could have answered back then but you'd be hopless for now. It doesn't happen very often, I've been here for a while and only now thought to ask about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that the question owner can do that nobody else can is accepting an answer. If you have already done that on your old questions, all is well; if not - it's not a huge problem, there's plenty of un-accepted good answers in the system.

You can of course flag the question and ask a moderator to disassociate the questions from your account, but then they're just completely orphaned with no real gain, and it's manual work for mods or even the site's developers.

You can also flag the questions and ask a moderator to make them Community Wiki, which will make it very easy for others to edit. However, answers to the question become Community Wiki as well, and stop gaining rep for answerers. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Once a question has become a community wiki, can the choice of accepted answer be changed by the community?

Comment: @alan no. There are requests to make it exactly that way, but they have all been declined so far, with the main argument being that "accepted" is a personal signal from the OP whether the answer worked for them. It's not to be regarded as a globally binding signal for "this is the only correct answer", so it's not important to make it community administered

Comment: Thanks, you've all been super helpfull. I'll keep control of the question in question.